# Regular expression is not working for numbers in jsp java

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

what I want is If the enter text box value is in format or not (1-10 number hyphen number) i did this for one pattern matching `/^[\d]+([-][\d]+)?$/g  but it allows only 0-9(single digits) i not taking 11-20(double digits)` I need to allow any type digits like 10-11 and how can i do this

```
var txt =  document.getElementById("txtShareCount").value;      
        if(txt.match(/^[\d]+([-][\d]+)?$/g)){       
            return true;
            }           
        else if(!txt.match( /^[\d]+([-][\d]+)?$/g)){
            alert("Pleae Enter Share count this(1-10) format");
            document.getElementById("txtShareCount").focus();
            return false;
            }
        else{return true;}
```

Comment: What does Java and JSP have to do with it?

Comment: so add a + to say one or more

Comment: i tested your code working fine @Antony

Comment: @JYoThI, have you test with 11-20 like this

Comment: yeah i tested that too @Antony

Comment: But i am not getting @JYoThI when i take 11-20 like this it shows `alert message`

Comment: can you check my below answer snippet @Antony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i'm posting the OP post as executable snippet to show his code is working perfect . i said in comment he didn't accept that . so only i'm posting this snippet .

1) Additionally i applied only `trim()`

```js
$('#ss').click(function(){
 
 var txt =  $("#txtShareCount").val();      
        if(txt.trim().match(/^[\d]+([-][\d]+)?$/g)){
  
            alert("hi valid format ");
            }           
        else if(!txt.trim().match(/^[\d]+([-][\d]+)?$/g)){
            alert("Pleae Enter Share count this(1-10) format");
            $("#txtShareCount").focus();
            return false;
            }
        else{
   
         alert("hi valid format ");
            }
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="txtShareCount" name="myanswer" class="myinput"></div>


<input type="button" id="ss" value="submit" >
```

Comment: mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @Antony

Answer (score 0):

The regex `^[\d]+([-][\d]+)?$` accomplishes what you need

Comment: when i take `^[\d]+([-][\d]+)?$` this expression it shows error it's not working

Comment: perhaps you need to trim your input or something? This regex is definitely correct for your use case.